# Keyboard not showing on activity start: Android phones

Tags: android, android-activity, android-keypad

I have an edittext in my activity, and on activity and on create view
I am setting the focus on the activity. while setting focus, I am also
trying to show the keyboard. It works on some devices, but on others it
just doesn't show.

I tried to step through the code and found that the view is not created, when
the show keyboard is called. Maybe that is the reason.

I am not sure what the problem is. Is there a way to make sure, that if a edit text
is in focus, the keyboard shows up on app start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can try to show the Soft Keyboard by calling the following line during onCreate:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with this is that they keyboard will show up, even when the app resumes, regardless of if the edittext is in focus or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, add this attribute to the `<activity>` tag for the Activity you want the keyboard shown:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`